# Looping through and sending to modal

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to understand why when I click on the button below I get three different objects before it says that invoice is undefined.

```
<tr :key="invoice" v-for="(invoice, index) in invoices">
    <td><button @click.prevent="openEdit(index)" Edit Invoice</button></td>
</tr>

openEdit(index) {
    var invoice = this.invoices.splice(index, 1)[0];
    this._beforeEditingCache = Object.assign({}, invoice);
    console.log(invoice);
    Bus.$emit('editting', { invoice: invoice, phase: this.phase, editModalName: this.editModalName });
},
```

Comment: `index` is only an integer and there is no object being passed for you to splice.

Comment: Suggestion on what I should do instead? I still need the full object because in the parent component I'm passing the object to this component's sibling.

Comment: What do you bean by ***I get three different objects before it says that invoice is undefined***? Your code seems to work for me.

Comment: Sorry. I click the button three times and get three different objects in the console.log. After those three button clicks then it starts saying that invoice is undefined.

Comment: Which makes complete sense. This code `var invoice = this.invoices.splice(index, 1)[0];` removes an element from the `this.invoices` array every time you click. Your invoices should have three elements. The fourth time it is empty, then you get `undefined`.

Comment: How many invoices are you starting with? And is `invoices` an Array or an Object?

Answer (score 1):

*After a long time i think i understood that question*

> You want to open a modal with the values of table row that gets clicked.

*I made a jsfiddle for this.Take a look here `:https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/eywraw8t/5415/`

*That fiddle is very simple.I suggest you to use the modal as child component.*

But if you using vue it would be vuetiful to use **vuetify**.Take a look to this table which includes edit,delete and add new item. [click here to see](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#example-crud)

Comment: After a lonnng time of thinking, i found your post thank you @roli roli   XD